# TextChanged/KeyDown for Entry/TextBox

Tags: tkinter, python-3.4, textchanged, tkinter-entry

I wrote following script based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4140437/python-tkinter-interactively-validating-entry-widget-content):

```
from tkinter import *

class MainWindow(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.geometry("500x300+433+234")
        self.title("Hallo")

        self.__tbIn_Txt = StringVar(None, "Hallo")
        self.__tbIn = Entry(self, textvariable = self.__tbIn_Txt, validate = "all")
        self.__tbIn.config(validatecommand = (self.register(self.__check),))
        self.__tbIn.pack()

    def __check(self):
        print("Check")

    def show(self):
        self.mainloop()

wMain = MainWindow()
wMain.show()
```

`__check` fires only the first time I click the Textbox/Entry, but never again. I want to achieve a KeyDown/KeyUp/KeyPress/TextChanged behavior, but it seems that my script results in a OnClick event. How to make the textbox call `__check` for every change in the Entry's value?

I am running Python 3.4 (64-bit) on Windows 7 64-bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The validatecommand must return True or False, or tkinter will cancel further validation.

Comment: Worth noting there are other ways in which further validation can be cancelled, in particular, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1019782/python-tkinter-entry-fun).  Not directly relevant to this question but a common and difficult to find problem with validation.